# How to trigger iOS push notification for individual users using webhook

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have written a web app in PHP which is an MVP for a product I am launching. Uptake is good and I have active users.

I notify users of certain events right now by integrating with Twilio and sending them an SMS when activity happens on their account.

I would like to release an iOS companion app so that I could notify them via native push message as Twilio SMS costs are decreasing the viability of my product and I do not want increase the monthly price.

I have researched various third party tools such as Pusher, Pushover and Onesignal but none of them seem to fit my need, as far as I can tell.

How could I trigger a custom push notification to an iOS user using my iOS companion app? Ideally I would swap out the Twilio api call and insert something else that called the push message.